# Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonString' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument' in MongoDB .NET Driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I am facing a problem while trying to run an aggregation pipeline using MongoDB .NET client. My code looks like so:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetPopularTags(int count)
    {
        var events = _database.GetCollection<Event>(_eventsCollectionName);

        var agg = events.Aggregate();
        var unwind = agg.Unwind<Event, Event>(e => e.Tags);
        var group = unwind.Group(e => e.Tags, v => new { Tag = v.Key, Count = v.Count() });
        var sort = group.SortByDescending(e => e.Count);
        var project = group.Project(r => r.Tag);
        var limit = project.Limit(count);
        var result = await limit.SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        return result;
    }
```

(separate vars for each stage are just for debugging purposes)

While trying to get the result of the pipeline (last var) I get a following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonString' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument'

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**SOLUTION**

I finally figured out that the fact that I was getting an exception at the last line had nothing to do with where the error was. I tried running `.SingleOrDefault()` on every stage to see outputs and I noticed that my pipeline had a couple of issues.

1. My unwind stage was trying to return an `Event` object, but since it was unwinding `Tags` property (which was a `List<string>`), it was trying to set it to `string` and was throwing an exception. I solved that issue by letting it set an output type to the default of `BsonDocument` and then in next stage using `["Tags"]` accessor to get the value I need. It looked something like this:

   ```
   var dbResult = await events.Aggregate()
       .Unwind(e => e.Tags)
       .Group(e => e["Tags"], v => new { Tag = v.Key, Count = v.Count() })
   ```
2. My project stage was not working for some reason. I was not able to get the `Tag` property (which turned out to be a `BsonValue` type) to be converted to `string`. In the end I deleted that stage and replaced it with a `dbResult.Select(t => t.Tag.AsString)` to cast it to a string. Not the most elegant solution, but better than nothing.

In the end my code ended up looking like so:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetPopularTags(int count)
    {
        var events = _database.GetCollection<Event>(_eventsCollectionName);

        var dbResult = await events.Aggregate()
        .Unwind(e => e.Tags)
        .Group(e => e["Tags"], v => new { Tag = v.Key, Count = v.Count() })
        .SortByDescending(e => e.Count)
        .Limit(count)
        .ToListAsync();

        var result = dbResult.Select(t => t.Tag.AsString);

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem you're facing can be basically simplified to below line of code:

```
var agg = collection.Aggregate().Project(x => x.Tag);
```

Where `Tag` is a `string` property in your model.

It appears that `Aggregate()` and all the MongoDB driver operators are closer to Aggregation Framework than C# syntax allows them to be.

Based on your code the `result` variable is supposed to be of type `String` which gets translated by the driver into `MongoDB.Bson.BsonString` however Aggregation Framework always returns BSON documents (single one in this case) so MongoDB .NET driver cannot handle such deserialization in the runtime (`BsonDocument -> BsonString`).

First workaround is obvious - return anything that resembles BSON document and can be deserialized from `BsonDocument` type like:

```
collection.Aggregate().Project(x => new { x.Tag });
```

and then map results in memory (same query is run behind the scenes)

Another approach: translate your query into LINQ using `.AsQueryable()` which allows you to return results in more flexible manner:

```
collection.AsQueryable().Select(x => x.Tag);
```

In both cases the query that's generated for my projection looks the same:

```
{aggregate([{ "$project" : { "Tag" : "$Tag", "_id" : 0 } }])}
```

Comment: I fortunately figured it out, but it was neither easy nor pleasant. I am going to accept your answer as correct since it helped me get on the right track. I will edit my question with what I actually did to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but this had a similar issue and this would have solved it for me:

You will want to make an intermediate class to represent group   `{ Tag = v.Key, Count = v.Count() }` and then change the Project to this.

```
.Project(Builders<YourIntermediateClass>.Projection.Expression(x => x.Tag))
```